# class vs helper routines - C++

Tags: c++, c, oop

I am new to C++ and come from C background.

I am currently working on a C++ project and as I am adding code, quite often I find myself asking of I should just have a set of helper routines or create a dedicated class for them.

Any suggestions on this please? I can see if there is code resuability element, or commonlaties then creating a class makes sense. But if, say, the code in a set of helper routines will be used only for a dedicated task for a single functionality only, what would I gain by putting them in classes?

I realise my question is quite abstract and perhaps vague but any suggestions/best practices would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: [This question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134448/where-should-i-put-functions-that-are-not-related-to-a-class) may be of interest to you.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you who contributed. It has definitely clarified a lot of concepts for me.

Answer (score 10):

Use classes when you are doing object-oriented programming, i.e. when there's some kind of **object** type being manipulated, not when you're just writing utility functions.

More specifically, when in C you'd have a

```
typedef struct { /*...*/ } Foo;
```

with assorted

```
Foo *make_foo();
void print_foo(FILE *, Foo const *);
// etc.
```

you should put the functions that operate on `Foo` objects in a `class Foo` instead. But when you've implemented a bunch of useful math operations that take and return only floating-point numbers, by all means, make them freestanding functions, and consider using namespaces instead of classes to group them together.

The great thing about C++ is that it doesn't force the class-based approach on you [like Java does](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html); it's not a good match for every problem domain.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on the functions.  If they manipulate a common set of data,
it makes sense to put the data in a class, and make them members.  If
they're more or less independent of one another, putting them in a class
is actually misleading; it suggests a relationship that doesn't exist.

At any rate, don't be afraid to use free functions when they are more
appropriate.

Comment: +1 for most reasonable answer given. People too often forget C++ is multi-paradigm language and not everything has to be OOP in C++.

Comment: +1 for "don't be afraid" -- C++ has been too often advertised as an OOP language rather than a multi-paradigm language where OOP is just one of many *options*.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion in good OO design you should not make any helper class. Each class should represent some object in the real world and should contains methods which represent the actions that this object does. In real world we have not any action which is unrelated to some object. So I believe that helper classes or static methods are a hell in OO development :). Should be mentioned that if class you created does not represent any object of your system and it is for internal using only (just used in your methods and would not be presented in uml) it could be moved to another submodule project.

Comment: There are certainly cases where helper classes are appropriate: the proxy pattern, for example, or observers.  But each class should represent a coherent entity, even if it doesn't correspond to something in the real world.  A class which is just a collection of unrelated (static?) functions is bad design.

Comment: @JamesKanze yes such type of classes should be in some other project which represent another part of the world. Design patterns should not represent what they are doing but just should be invisibly presented in your project (I mean you should never give the name Visitor to an class which implements the visitor design pattern).

Comment: Also why do you have an class with an collection of unrelated functions?? Why did you make it?? which is the concept of making such classes? My concept is the representation of real world which is the basic concept of OOP. So which is your concept? Just because I need it?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some reasons why making a class might be useful:

- You avoid name clash by the class name.
- The class name might simplify the functions names and/or make them more readable.
- If your functions require enums those enums will be neatly packaged with your functions
- If your functions access constants the constants will be packaged into the class.
- If you functions support settings (or will in a future version) implementing them as non-static methods makes multi-threading easier.

Comment: Points 1 through 3 can often be tackled more cleanly with namespaces instead of classes.

Answer (score 1):

If the functions maintain no internal state and are reentrant, I can't see the point of defining a class with static members or creating objects of a class just to call methods - it would be pointless typing.

Answer (score 1):

> What is a `class` ?

In the strictest OOP sense, a class is a bunch of related data with methods to operate on those data. However C++ is far from being a pure OOP language, and **encapsulation** is a much better aim that some religious overzealous mindless utopy.

> Which data should be put into a `class` ?

Related data should generally be tied together, for example, the length of a buffer and the associated buffer belong together, for you cannot use the buffer without its length.

Encapsulation (and the Law of Demeter) then advise that they should be `private`, so that clients of the class do not depend on its internal representation. In practice though, it is viable that some information be exposed to the public directly, to avoid creating a bunch of getters/setters functions (though those have advantages of their own).

At the very least though, data that have *invariants* (*) associated should be `private` so that those invariants can be *enforced*.

> Which functions should be put into a `class` ?

Any function that **need** direct access to the class private data should be a class method. A notable exception are operators, whose signature is fixed. This can be solved by giving them a *friendly* access.

The corrolary is that any function that does not need direct access (because other methods provide sufficient information for its functionality) is better implemented as a free-function. This *increases encapsulation*.

The typical example is that `std::string::find_first_of` (and related) should have been implemented as free function.

> What is a *blob* ?

Sometimes you find yourself having a bunch of related data, but with no strong invariant between themselves, for example:

```
struct State {
  Language language;
  Page currentPage;
};
```

If you change the language, it does not change the page, and vice-versa. The two are merely together for convenience. This is not a `class` proper, and is sometimes referred to as a `blob` because of its unstructured shape. More encapsulation is not necessary here, and methods are thus superfluous (though a constructor can help).

---

(*) On *invariants*

As explained, the length of a buffer is tightly tied to the buffer itself, they should be changed together. Therefore, there should exist a buffer class that has two members: the length and the buffer, and that manages those two so that the *invariant* that `length` is the length of `buffer` always hold (as far as external observers are concerned).

On the other hand, if you create a `std::string filename;` attribute and hide it into `BigObject`, alongside `logmessage` and `anotherthingy`, then you are doing it wrong. `BigObject` should have a `Filename filename;` attribute, and let it up to the `Filename` class to maintain this invariant.

Answer (score 1):

The are a few different types of encapsulation and abstraction that C++ lets you express more directly than C, but no hard-and-fast rules.

### Invariants

If you currently have a structure (or even some primitives you usually pass around together), but you want to enforce some invariants which make your code easier to reason about, there's a strong case for using a class with private data members and accessors which can maintain those invariants.

The obvious example is `std::string` versus `{ char const *p; int length; }`. With the second form you have to manually handle (de)allocation, decide whether it's legal for p to be NULL and make sure you check that everywhere, manually enforce nul-termination if required, etc.

### Interfaces and Inheritance

You can implement these in C: interface ~= structure containing function pointers, inheritance ~= making the "base" structure the first member of the "derived" one and merrily casting between them. Indeed, these mechanisms are widely used in C frameworks.

However, if you want runtime polymorphism, compiler-supported inheritance and virtual method dispatch in C++ are generally much cleaner and clearer.

---

Apart from these, there are lots of situations that can be expressed in terms of classes, but don't have to be.

Collections of mutually-related functions and structures *can* be put in a class, but just grouping them in a namespace and leaving the data in publicly-accessible `struct`s can be fine too. Indeed, even if the data has invariants, minimising the number of privileged methods and putting the other associated logic in free functions is better style (it reduces the number of places invariants need to be checked or guaranteed).

Some types of variation are better expressed by compile-time than by runtime polymorphism (ie, templates). In this case you don't need an inheritance relationship because templates can use duck-typing.

Dependency-hiding is just as easily accomplished with an opaque pointer typedef as it is with a pimpl or handle/body class, the exception being where the public outer class needs to do something more to manage the lifetime of the impl pointer than is provided by shared_ptr or unique_ptr.

And, of course, some code is naturally functional or procedural, and there's no benefit to shoehorning it into a class.

Answer (score -2):

I'm in the same condition. I just came from C world and now I've been working with C++.

My suggestion is to create a class and call it's methods.

Maybe in the future, someone could use that same class ;)